# Sample web application in java with security constraints in web.xml

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, authorization, security

I am looking for sample web application in JAVA which has security-constraints in its web.xml file to handle authentication and authorization. Basically I want to see how web security is implemented with security constraints.

I goggled about it and mostly could find example of web.xml file which shows how can one provide web security with security constraints. but I would like to have may be small but complete web application in java which exhibits this concept.

Could someone please suggest some source for this ? I am new to web application development and web security both.

Pl note that I don't want to give any security to existing web application I need some sample application in java which has some authentication-authorization mechanism. I need it to do some experiments as part of my study.

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for a way to have user management system, i.e. add/remove/edit user into your system? that's not possible with security constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reading [Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) in the [Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/index.html)?  The tutorial bundle contains plenty of examples.

You can download a ZIP file of examples [here](http://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

[The Java EE 6 Tutorial, Part VII : Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html)