# Are there solutions to access security constraints of web application?

Tags: java, security, servlets, web-applications

I have configured the access constraints of my web application in the web.xml file by **security-constraint** tag.

Now I want to read the configuration in my java code, for example, in my servlet.
For example:Get which roles are allowed to access the given url or url pattern; Get the role list of the application; Get the roles of current user;
I could not found the API from the Java EE specification; I also could not found any answer by google.
Could you help me please? 
Are there solutions for some specific web server, such as websphere or glassfish?
Or it is not possible to solve this problem, the only way is just parsing the web.xml by myself?

Comment: Do you not get this value using the getServletContext()?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600157/sample-web-application-in-java-with-security-constraints-in-web-xml

Comment: @aksappy, thanks, but unfortunately there is no API to get this information by using ServletContext;

Comment: @Punit Patel, thanks, I have read that thread before, but it's not the answer to my question.

Comment: Do you have an option of using Shiro or Spring Security?